# How to use GWT $entry Function in JSNI?

Tags: java, javascript, html, gwt, jsni

The $entry function in GWT is used to get uncaught exceptions reported from JavaScript to GWT.

**What is the difference between the following $entry calls and which one is the correct one?**

The following versions call instance Java functions.

Version 1:

```
public final native String test(double arg) /*-{
    var instance = this;

    var callExternal = $entry(function(arg) {
       return instance.@com.example.MyClass::javaFunction(D)(arg);
    });

    var x = callExternal(arg);
}-*/;
```

Version 2:

```
public final native String test(double arg) /*-{
    var x = $entry(instance.@com.example.MyClass::javaFunction(D)(arg));
}-*/;
```

**Is there a different use whether I use static or non static java functions?**

**Update:**

The following versions call static Java functions.

Version 1:

```
public final native String test(double arg) /*-{

    var callExternal = $entry(function(arg) {
       return@com.example.MyClass::javaFunction(D)(arg);
    });

    var x = callExternal(arg);
}-*/;
```

Version 2:

```
public final native String test(double arg) /*-{
    var x = $entry(@com.example.MyClass::staticJavaFunction(D)(arg));
}-*/;
```

Comment: Are you able to access variable `x` or `callExternal` from javascript in any case?

Comment: It depends on you application design whether to use static or non static java functions. It's simple. If there is only single instance of that class then you can use static function but in case of multiple instance you have to use non static function to maintain the state of object.

Comment: @Braj The code is JavaScript from a JSNI function.

Comment: I don't know what do you want to achieve? You can't access variable `x` or `callExternal` from JavaScript in any case until and unless it is bind with `$wnd`.

Comment: @Braj See my edit I think now it is much more clear.

Answer (score 2):

The second one is wrong: it calls the method then wraps the result. It's useless, possibly even broken.

`$entry` wraps a function in another function that uses a try/catch.

Comment: Does is matter if it is a static function or not?

Comment: It isnt wrong because of wrapping the call, its wrong because of *how* it wraps it. Put the (arg) after the $entry() closes, and it is back to less useless, and won't throw exceptions by existing.

Comment: Is there a rule of thumb when to use $entry and when not? I mean is it a good practice to use it whenever I create a new JavaScript object inside a JSNI function or whenever I call a Java callback function inside JSNI?

Comment: Use `$entry` as soon as your pass a reference to a Java method to some JS that will call it back "later". If you know it'll be used synchronously then `$entry` is not needed (but would be harmless; I don't think it would really impact performance; though it depends how the function is used / at which rate it'll be called)

Answer (score 1):

Question:

Is there a different use whether I use static or non static java functions?

Answer:

There is a error while accessing `static` java function `javaFunction` using `instance` as follow `instance.@com.example.MyClass::javaFunction(D)(arg);`

Error:

```
Unnecessary qualifier on static method 'com.example.MyClass.javaFunction'
```

---

--EDIT--

Both are working fine for static java function as shown below:

```
public static void staticJavaFunction(double d){
    System.out.println(d);
}

public final native String test(double arg) /*-{
    var x = $entry(@com.gwt.test.client.GWTTestProject::staticJavaFunction(D)(arg));
}-*/; 

public final native String test(double arg) /*-{
    var callExternal = $entry(function(arg) {
       return @com.gwt.test.client.GWTTestProject::staticJavaFunction(D)(arg);
    });

    var x = callExternal(arg);
}-*/;
```

Both are also working fine for non static java function as shown below:

Note: just single change in version 2 where `var instance = this;` was missing.

```
public void javaFunction(double d){
    System.out.println(d);
}

public final native String test(double arg) /*-{
    var instance = this;
    var x = $entry(instance.@com.gwt.test.client.GWTTestProject::javaFunction(D)(arg));
}-*/;

public final native String test(double arg) /*-{
    var instance = this;

    var callExternal = $entry(function(arg) {
       return instance.@com.gwt.test.client.GWTTestProject::javaFunction(D)(arg);
    });

    var x = callExternal(arg);
}-*/;
```

I prefer version 2 in both the cases.

Comment: The "version 2" with instance methods is wrong. `this` doesn't work that way in JavaScript: it depends of how you call a method, not where it comes from; so you *have* to use "version 1" for an instance method (and make sure you don't use the `this` keyword within the closure)

Comment: But version 1 is also using `this` for instance method. All are working fine.

Answer (score 0):

You could try it:

```
public final native String test1(double arg) /*-{
    var instance = this;
    var x = $entry(function(a) {
        return instance.@com.example.MyClass::javaFunction(D)(a);
    })(arg);
    return x;
}-*/;
```

For static invocation you can use:

```
public final native String test2(double arg) /*-{
    var x = $entry(@com.example.MyClass::staticJavaFunction(D))(arg);
    return x;
}-*/;
```